# Python: Saving lists that are outputs of a for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a number of columns in an Excel spreadsheet (all different lengths) to import into Python, and I want to save each of these columns as a named list within Python. There are quite a few columns so I'd like to use a for loop to achieve this. I can import all of the columns and print them successfully during each iteration, but I can't work out how I can save these lists under the name of the column? e.g. from column "1", I would like to end up with a list named "1" that consists of the 20 values in that column.

Apologies if this is a very simple question or there's a better way of doing it - I'm still pretty new to Python.

Here's what I've got so far that extracts and prints the columns as lists:

```
lists = 'SpreadsheetFilePath.xlsx'  
columns = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "6", "17", "18"]
    
All_Data = pd.read_excel(lists, sheet_name = 'Schedule')

for i in columns:
    newlist = All_Data[i].values.tolist()
    newerlist = [x for x in newlist if str(x) != 'nan']
    print(newerlist)
```

I essentially want to save newerlist under a list called "1" before the loop repeats.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In CS, this is called an associative array. It's a data structure that stores a collection of key/value pairs. It allows you to associate a key with a value. In your case, the key is the column name and the value is an array/list of column values for that specific column. In Python, you would use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use a dictionary of lists, where keys are column names and values are lists:

```
values_by_column = {}
for i in columns:
    newlist = All_Data[i].values.tolist()
    newerlist = [x for x in newlist if str(x) != 'nan']
    values_by_column[i] = newerlist

print(values_by_column["1"])
print(values_by_column["2"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a dictionary where the keys are your variable list names e.g. "1" and the value attached to each key is its list. Adapting your code:

```
lists = 'SpreadsheetFilePath.xlsx'  
columns = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "6", "17", "18"]
    
All_Data = pd.read_excel(lists, sheet_name = 'Schedule')

# Initialise a dictionary
dict_of_lists = dict()

for i in columns:
    newlist = All_Data[i].values.tolist()
    newerlist = [x for x in newlist if str(x) != 'nan']
    # Assign the list for column i to the key i
    dict_of_lists[i] = newerlist
```

You could then access each list by addressing its key in the dictionary e.g.

```
list_for_col_1 = dict_of_lists["1"]

for row in list_for_col_1:
    print(row)
```

Have a read of how dictionaries work in general and you should be flying. In general, whenever you find yourself wanting to do something that might require a dynamic number of variables or dynamic variable names like this, a dict will help